# How to set monitor time range in celery Flower monitor

Tags: celery, flower

We use Flower for celery monitoring. But how to set the monitor range for let's say a week?
Currently looks like it reloads each time on refresh.
[image]

UPDATE: image "mher/flower:0.9.5"